# After enable remote access, ROOT lost privileges and grant privilege to ROOT doesn't work

Tags: mysql, xampp

AFTER `update user set host='%' where user='root`, I lost some of the privileges from my MySQL root user. So I stopped the server and started it with --skip-grant-tables

`msqld --skip-grant-tables`

and I tried

```
mysql>update mysql.user set grant_priv = 'Y' where user = 'root';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql>FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

This doesn't work for me. When I log in as root, I still can't see the MYSQL database.

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please help. I've tried all the solutions still can't restore the privileges for ROOT, always got the "0 row affected" result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

**Update**

Run this command to check your current privileges

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;
```

It is a bad practice to insert/update/delete from `mysql.*` tables and `information_schema.*` tables using direct SQL DML statements.

**Update 2**

Can you post the results of this command

```
  SELECT (
      Host, 
      Grant_priv, 
      Super_priv 
    ) 
  FROM mysql.user
  WHERE user = 'root';
```

All of the `_priv` columns should have a value `Y`. And the `Host` should be `localhost`.

Comment: does not work, I got `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)` . I forgot to mention that I lost the privileges AFTER enable remote access  @Eternal-Learner

Comment: You started with `--skip-grant-tables` right? is there a `root` user? run `select user,host from mysql.user where user = 'root'` to check. If not, you need to create the user first

Comment: Yes there is a root user, and the host is linux. But I have to start the server normally to run `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER; ` or any `GRANT` clauses, otherwise I would get `ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement`.  Anyway, I log in as ROOT and checked privileges, `Grants for @localhost` are `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ''@'localhost'` @Eternal-Learner

Comment: See my updated answer. When you set `host` to `%`, it does not include `localhost`. Mostly your issue will go away if you change the `host` back to `localhost`. To include bother `localhost` and `remote` access, you should have two entries in `mysql.user` table.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that `host must be localhost` thing until you pointed it out clearly. I've fixed this by adding a new `root` user and setting host to be `localhost`.  Thank you so much for your help. @Eternal-Learner